# How to get total count of Records including line item in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

```
var columns = [];
var filters= [];
filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('mainline', null, 'is', 'false'));
columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid', null, 'COUNT'));

var results = nlapiSearchRecord('salesorder', null, filters, columns);
```

When we use this we only get count of total grouped sales order. I want count when mainline is false. Is there any faster way to get all the count including line items. By this i mean to say count of all repeted sales order for different line items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function countTotalRecords(type){

  var count =0;
  var i=0;
  var j=1000;
  var columns = [];
  var filters= [];
  columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid'));

  var search = nlapiCreateSearch(type,filters,columns);
  var resultSet = search.runSearch();

  do{
     var result =resultSet.getResults(i,j);
     count += result.length;
     i=j;
     j=j+1000;

  }while(result.length == 1000);

  return count;
}
```

I found a way to count the total Records including line items. Thanks